# Searching Multiple Items Using Combo box and List box for a ms access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, filtering, multipleselection

I have a split form with a combo box (named cmb_KostenstellenAll) that shows cost centers. I can filter my form with cost center from this combo box (My form comes from a query called qryFürFormular).I added a list box (named lbx_KsAll) to make multiple selections when applying the filter. If  is selected in the combo box, the list box becomes visible and I can select more than one cost center. Codes to do this:

```
Private Sub cmb_KostenstellenAll_AfterUpdate()


If Me.cmb_KostenstellenAll = "<Multiple selection>" Then
  
Me.lbx_KsAll.Visible = True

else
 
Me.lbx_KsAll.Visible = False

Me.Requery

End If

end sub


Private Sub lbx_KsAll_AfterUpdate()

Dim varItem As Variant

Dim strCriteria As String

Dim TempMultiState As TempVar

For Each varItem In Me!lbx_KsAll.ItemsSelected

strCriteria = strCriteria & "," & Me!lbx_KsAll.ItemData(varItem) & ""

Next varItem

If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
   
Exit Sub

Else
   
strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)

   TempVars!TempMultiState = strCriteria

   MsgBox (TempVars!TempMultiState)

End If

End Sub
```

However, when I click the search button (named cmd_Search) with two selected cost center (called Sondermachninenbau and Testing), I get an error: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '([Kostenstellen_NEU] in (Sondermachninenbau,Testing))'.
I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub cmd_Suchen_Click()

Call Search

End Sub

Sub Search()

Dim myKS, strSQL, strCriteria As String

If IsNull(Me.cmb_KostenstellenAll) Then

ElseIf Me.cmb_KostenstellenAll = "<Multiple selection>" Then

       strCriteria = "[Kostenstellen_NEU] in (" & TempVars!TempMultiState & ")"

       MsgBox (TempVars!TempMultiState)

Else

   myKS = "[Kostenstellen_NEU]='" & Me.cmb_KostenstellenAll & "'"

   strCriteria = myKS

End If

strSQL = "select * from qryFürFormular where (" & strCriteria & ")"

Me.RecordSource = strSQL

Me.Requery

End Sub

Me.RecordSource = strSQL is highligted.

In the example where I got the code like this(He had a table called Customers and 
then created a form and added a subform with record source  Customers)  :

End If

strSQL = "select * from customers where (" & strCriteria & ")"

Me.customers_subform.Form.RecordSource = strSQL

Me.Customers_subform.FormRequery

End Sub
```

Comment: For a start, in cmd_Suchen_Click() that `ElseIf` should probably be a nested `If`. Then there is that extraneous `End Sub` in the middle.

Comment: `strCriteria = strCriteria & "," & Me!lbx_KsAll.ItemData(varItem) & ""` this line will not work. You have to use `AND`, `OR` logic.

Comment: The error complains about `([Kostenstellen_NEU] in (Sondermachninenbau,Testing))`  Modify your code so that it adds quotes around the text values making it look like `([Kostenstellen_NEU] in ('Sondermachninenbau','Testing'))`

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can make multiple choices. However, when I wanted to prepare a report containing this filter (there is a create report button), it did not apply directly. How do I get the report to apply the filter?
My report create code:
`Private Sub cmd_BerichtAll_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "All", acViewPreview

End Sub`